# Do I need to close my question if its a duplicate, but a better one?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have just asked a question about some operator in JS ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891262/what-the-expression-expression-means-in-javascript-when-doing-condition-evalu/41892914#41892914)) and I got an answer which explains the question well.

Then moderators pointed out that my question has already an answer. ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090434/why-does-this-javascript-work))

I think my question is better "google-able" as it is a more general question and the answer is better quality as well. (Why some mechanism works like this in js, than the other question which ask why this pice of code works somehow.)

Should I close my question as a duplicate, or can I vote somehow to close the other question?

I ask here in general, although I have an specific example, but my question is what to do in general when I think a newer question asks better than some old one.

Comment: Typically it is the one with the best answer(s) that should be the dupe target.  I'm not a JS person so I won't weigh in on the but as far as age of the post goes that is not a factor.

Comment: I can see why you think the answer is better, but I don't understand why you think your question is better. To me, it seems less clear and less general. Besides, even if it somehow more "Google-able", closing it as a duplicate will still leave it as a search target.

Comment: @CodyGray doesn't duplicate questions got deleted over time?

Comment: "but I don't understand why you think your question is better." - I think nobody will search for this issue as "Why does this JavaScript work?" Its hard to imagine a more general title for any question. I would totally skip a google result like this even if its comes up.

Comment: @NoNameProvided As a rule duplicates don't get deleted *only* because they are duplicates. The automatic deletion script has rules to avoid deleting questions only because they are duplicate. And this is also the custom among people who have deletion votes: we don't delete duplicates only because they are duplicates. There has to be another reason: the duplicate is awful, or it is a duplicate of a question that has been asked a thousand times (the additional duplicate is not useful, even as a sign-post), etc.

Comment: Yes, the other question has a bad title. It should be edited.

Comment: I think both questions are trivially answered by reading the documentation, and indeed both of the questions' answers reference MDN. Given that the questions have been asked (and will likely be asked again because why research when you can just ask?), the answer on the OP's question is better and should be the duplicate target, in my opinion. I've voted as such.

Comment: @NoNameProvided, The script which automatically deletes posts is called Roomba. It has a [complex set of criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) which must be satisfied for a question to be auto-deleted (Roomb'ed). Questions closed as duplicates still must meet multiple criteria to be Roomba'ed. One criteria that your question does not meet is that it must have no answers. Thus, your question will not be Roomba'ed. There are [multiple other criteria which your question does not meet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtCAB.png), all of which would have to change for it to be Roomba'ed.

Comment: In my opinion, the originally proposed dup-target is not a good question to use as a duplicate target.. A better dup-target for your question is [What does a comma do in JavaScript expressions?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3561043). Another dup-target alternative would be [Why does \[5,6,8,7\]\[1,2\] = 8 in Javascript](//stackoverflow.com/q/7421013)